# How to show item ID when printing SharePoint item

Tags: sharepoint-2010

When using right click -> Print Target to print a list item from a view, is there a way to include the item ID in the printout?  The view includes the ID.  Users have been maintaining a custom column for “ID Number” so that they can match the printout to the item in the list, and they wonder why this is necessary.